# Remove vertical scroll in the following code

Tags: html, css, percentage

I need something like HTML code and css following below. But now browser has showing vertical scroll. How to remove vertical scroll. Code is in the jsFiddile http://jsfiddle.net/jHVc7/

```
<style type="text/css">
    html,body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        header{
            height: 50px;
            background: #84ff00;
        }
        section{
            background: #139e7f;
            height: 100%;
        }
        section div{
            width: 180px;
            float: left;
            background: #d0b107;
            height: 100%;
        }
        section aside{
            width: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #0edb09;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <section>
            <div>a</div>
            <aside>b</aside>
        </section>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your html,body{ .... }

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

See DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/jHVc7/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have 50px height in the header and 100% height for .section
now the total height of your body is 100% + 50px , so you are getting vertical scroll.

You can apply overflow:hidden in body or adjust the height of .section

```
 html,body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

use the following class. This should work.

```
section{
        background: #139e7f;
        height:calc(100% - 50px);
    }
```

Comment: do you know how to solve "100% + 50px" problem other than overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can add

`overflow: hidden` to `html,body` property

```
html,body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```